# POST data needs a time stamp - Web Requests

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, post, httpwebrequest

So I'm writing an application and sending a post request to authorize a facebook application. Most of the dynamic information in the post data I can find parsing the page, but a part of the post data has a time stamp, which changes, but I'm not sure how to get this value. This is what it looks like in the post data:

```
&locale=en_US&ttstamp=265817055695648116725765122&
```

How should I go about generating that number? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use [`ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx), just like-

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.example.com?..&locale=en_US&ttstamp=265817055695648116725765122&..");
string param = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("ttstamp");
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to create this number so that they can send it rather than receiving and decoding it